# Is money value between X and Y?

Tags: sql, case, currency

This is an easy process in excel using a vlookup with the approximate match but I can not make it work with SQl for some reason I am sure I am doing this hard way any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a sample of the results I am getting:

```
Player ID    ADT         ADT Tier
103         31.25        2
112          6.03        6
114        498.26        7
117       1330.82        4
131         10.01        NULL
```

Here is what that sample should look like:

```
Player ID    ADT         ADT Tier
103         31.25        11
112          6.03        NULL
114        498.26        7
117       1330.82        4
131         10.01        NULL
```

Below is the code I am trying to use.

```
Select S.Meta_ID as "Player ID"
,Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) as ADT
,case 
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '3500' and '1000000' then '1'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '2000' and '3499.99' then '2'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '1500' and '1999.99' then '3'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '1000' and '1499.99' then '4'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '750'  and '999.99'  then '5'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '500'  and '749.99'  then '6'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '300'  and '499.99'  then '7'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '150'  and '299.99'  then '8'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '75'   and '149.99'  then '9'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '40'   and '74.99'   then '10'
    when cast(Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2)as varchar) between '15'   and '39.99'   then '11'
    Else null
End as "ADT Tier"

From  dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S

Where S.GamingDate Between '06/1/2014' and '08/31/2014'
  And S.IDType = 'P'
  And S.StatType <> 'Poker'

Group by S.Meta_ID
```

Comment: can you give sample data from CDS_STATDAY table, also which RDBMS?

Comment: Why are you converting to varchar to do a numeric comparison?

Comment: your problem is trying to compare numbers converted to strings, just use numeric values.  Also, always specify a size when converting, using just "varchar" is very lazy. Do you know what the default size is when using just "varchar"? will your data fit into it? it doesn't take much to add the size: `varchar(25)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting as varchar which is causing your BETWEEN's to compare alphabetically, which is why your results are coming out wrong. Remove the cast statements as shown below:

```
Select S.Meta_ID as "Player ID"
,Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) as ADT
,case 
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 3500 and 1000000 then 1
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 2000 and 3499.99 then 2
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 1500 and 1999.99 then 3
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 1000 and 1499.99 then 4
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 750  and 999.99  then 5
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 500  and 749.99  then 6
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 300  and 499.99  then 7
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 150  and 299.99  then 8
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 75   and 149.99  then 9
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 40   and 74.99   then 10
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 15   and 39.99   then 11
    Else null
End as "ADT Tier"

From  dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S

Where S.GamingDate Between '06/1/2014' and '08/31/2014'
  And S.IDType = 'P'
  And S.StatType <> 'Poker'

Group by S.Meta_ID
```

To explain the results you are getting, alphabetically 31.25 is between 2000 and 3499.99, which is why you are getting 2 for ADT value for that row.

Comment: For completeness you should also change the between arguments to numeric, for xample `between 3500 and 1000000` instead of `between '3500' and '1000000'`.

Comment: Thank you so much I did not realize I could leave off the '' around numbers I am still very new to SQL that fixed this issue quite quickly. Now to write the code to do this for the other three items that need to tiered out like this and figure out how to find the best tier of the 4. Fun times for me :)